# Unit tests for Joomla 3 plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, unit-testing

I have written some moderately complicated software for my Joomla site and want to improve on my code base in coming releases.

To this end I am writing some unit tests however it's hard to run the tests on the full stack because I don't have a full installation of Joomla on my personal computer (I just have a dev environment and production environment running on vms)

What is the minimum setup I could reasonably create that would test my Joomla stack? Do I need a full local install or is there some other way?